# Rails update_all from associated_object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, update-all

I have a Glass object and a Prescription object, but i forgot to add timestamps to the Glass Object, so i created a migration to do that. However, not surprisingly all the objects have todays date and time.

`glass belongs_to :prescription prescription has_one :glass`

However, I can get the correct timestamp from the Prescription object. I just don't know how to do that. So I want to do something like

`Glass.update_all(:created_at => self.prescription.created_at)`

any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest thing to do is simply multiple SQL queries, it's a one off migration so no biggie I think. ActiveRecord update_all is meant to update the matching records with the same value so that won't work.

```
Glass.all.find_each do |glass|
   glass.update!(created_at: glass.prescription.created_at)
end
```

If you want one query (update based on a join - called "update from" in sql terms) it seems not straightforward in ActiveRecord (should work on MySQL but not on Postgres) https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13496 it will be easier to write raw SQL - this can help you get started https://www.dofactory.com/sql/update-join

Answer (score 0):

You can use [touch](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/touch) method

```
Prescription.find_each do |prescription|
  prescription.glass.touch(:created_at, time: prescription.created_at)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Believe me when I say that I'm on team "idiomatic Rails" and it's true that iterating through each record and updating it is probably more idiomatic, but `UPDATE FROM..` is *so incredibly more performant* and efficient (resources-wise) that unless the migration is iterating through < 1000 records, I prefer to do the in-SQL `UPDATE FROM`.

The particular syntax for doing an update from a join will vary depending on which SQL implementation you're running (Postgres, MySQL, etc.), but in general just execute it from a Rails DB connection.

```rb
InboundMessage.connection.execute <<-SQL
  UPDATE
    inbound_messages
  INNER JOIN notifications
    ON inbound_messages.message_detail_type = "Notification"
    AND inbound_messages.message_detail_id = notifications.id
  SET 
    inbound_messages.message_detail_type = notifications.notifiable_type,
    inbound_messages.message_detail_id = notifications.notifiable_id
  WHERE
    notifications.type = "foo_bar"
SQL
```